# Operator and operand don't agree ML

Tags: ml

I'm working on a function for class, and I am getting this error.

Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]

operator domain: 'Z list

operand:         'Y list -> 'Y list

in expression:
    null tl

```
fun removedub(L) =
  if (null L) then nil
  else if (null tl(L)) then hd(L)
  else if hd(L) = hd(tl(L)) then removedub(tl(L))
  else hd(L) :: removedub(tl(L));



val list = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c"];

removedub(list);
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, or really what is causing it, any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You set the parentheses wrong. When you write

```
null tl(L)
```

then that has the same meaning as

```
null(tl)(L)
```

However, you want

```
null(tl(L))
```